# Query to return exact match for item in comma delimited string using MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, where-clause

I am struggling with writing a MYSQL query in PHP that can find an exact match with one item in a comma delimited string. Note, for various reasons I cannot change the data model

```
Musicians
id|artist
1|beatles
2|rolling stones

$searchterm = "beatles"
```

It is easy to match the string exactly with:

```
WHERE artist = '$searchterm'
```

How could I determine an exact match in the following

```
Musicians
id|artist
1|beatles,the beatles,the fab four,fab four,fab for
2|rolling stones,the rolling stones,stones,the stones

$searchterm = "fab four"

//something like the following although it does not work

WHERE $searchterm IN artist
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:searchterm, artist)
```

Important notes:

- do not concatenate variables into the query string, as this makes your code inefficient and exposes you to SQL injection; instead, do use parameterized queries. Related reading: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716)
- storing delimited lists in a database column is bad practice; it basically defeats the purpose of a relational databases, and makes simple things unecessarily complicated (as you are starting to see). Recommended related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Comment: Thx I realize it is suboptimal in a dbase such as MYSQL. However, I can't change the data model and have to work with what is there.

Comment: I am getting a sql syntax error. with WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:'$searchterm',artist)...should it be something different? Also tried it without the '' around $searchterm with same error

Comment: OK. There should not be a : The syntax should be FIND_IN_SET('$needle',haystack)

Comment: @zztop: yes. The syntax I gave you makes use of a query parameter (see the first "important note").